# Android ListView - ArrayList only 7 items from 23 used - why?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I programmed my own ListView BaseAdapter. I've one ArrayList with 23 entrys. The first seven are from instance games and the next 16 from instance table. But If I run the ListView I only get the first seven items. If I don't reuse the convertview (...if(convertview==null || true){...) I get every 23 items. Is there a problem when not reuising the items?

```
package k0f.de.americanfootball;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by benjaminbecker on 26.02.16.
 */
public class AmericanFootballAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater inflator;
    private ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public AmericanFootballAdapter(Context context) {
        inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void setNewDataGames(ArrayList<Object> arrayList){
        this.arrayList=arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        Context context = parent.getContext();

        // falls nötig, convertView bauen
        // Holder bereits vorhanden
        if (convertView == null) {

            // Layoutdatei entfalten
            if((position%2)==0){
                convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.listitem_game, parent,
                        false);
            }else{
                convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.listitem_table, parent,
                        false);
            }

            // Holder erzeugen
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            Object ob = getItem(position);

            if(ob instanceof AmericanFootballDataGames){
                holder = holderGames(holder, convertView, context, (AmericanFootballDataGames) ob);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }

            if(ob instanceof AmericanFootballDataTable){
                holder = holderTable(holder, convertView, context, (AmericanFootballDataTable) ob);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }

        } else  {
            Log.v("Ben","HolderGame");
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } /*else {
            Log.v("Ben","HolderTable");
            holderG = (ViewHolderGame) convertView.getTag();
            convertView.setTag(holderG);
        }
*/
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv1, tv2, tv3;
    }

    private ViewHolder holderGames(ViewHolder holder, View convertView, Context context, AmericanFootballDataGames afdg){
        String erg = afdg.getTdheim() + " : " +
                afdg.getTdgast() + " (" +
                afdg.getQ1heim() + " : " +
                afdg.getQ1gast() + " , " +
                afdg.getQ2heim() + " : " +
                afdg.getQ2gast() + " , " +
                afdg.getQ3heim() + " : " +
                afdg.getQ3gast() + " , " +
                afdg.getQ4heim() + " : " +
                afdg.getQ4gast() + ")";

        holder.tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.game);
        holder.tv3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.erg);
        holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);

        holder.tv1.setText(afdg.getAnstoss()+System.getProperty("line.separator")+afdg.getDatum());
        holder.tv2.setText(afdg.getHeim() + System.getProperty("line.separator") + afdg.getGast());
        holder.tv3.setText(erg);

        if(afdg.getTdheim().toString()=="?") {
            holder.tv3.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorListHalfLight));
        }else{
            holder.tv3.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
            holder.tv3.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorListHalfDark));
        }

        return holder;
    }

    private ViewHolder holderTable(ViewHolder holder, View convertView, Context context, AmericanFootballDataTable afdt){
        holder.tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.game);
        holder.tv3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.erg);
        holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        holder.tv1.setText(Integer.toString(afdt.getPlatz()));
        holder.tv2.setText(afdt.getMannschaft());
        holder.tv3.setText(afdt.getPplus()+" "+afdt.getPminus());
        return holder;
    }
}
```

This are the screens with and without table data.

[image: Without table data]
[image: With table data]

Answer (score 1):

You're overriding getViewTypeCount() to return 2, which says that this adapter can handle two different kinds of views.  If you do this, you also have to override [getItemViewType()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) to return an int indicating which type of view is at the given position.  You then need to inflate the correct view for that position in getView() so that the view can be correctly recycled and reused by ListView for other items of that type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes tried with this and forget to remove the lines. Also without this parameter not all objects from the ArrayList will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake. Had to set the text on the holder before return convertView; and not in the if complex.